# DynamoDB cross-region replication AWS Java SDK

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I need to configure cross-region replication for my DynamoDb table. To try in manually I just used AWS Web Console where I configured Global Table with appropriate regions for replication through DynamoDb streams, it was pretty simple. Could somebody please advice me how can I do it using Java SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind that DyanmoDB now supports [global tables](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/global-tables/) as [announced on 29 November 2017](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/aws-launches-amazon-dynamodb-global-tables/). So you can probably replace your multitude of regional tables with global ones.

> Global Tables eliminates the difficult work of replicating data
> between regions and resolving update conflicts, enabling you to focus
> on your application’s business logic. In addition, Global Tables
> enables your applications to stay highly available even in the
> unlikely event of isolation or degradation of an entire region.

However to answer you queston directly, its not part of the AWS DynamoDB Java SDK. You have to use the dynamodb-cross-region-library from AWS labs.

> Cross-Region Replication
>
> Important
>
> AWS previously provided a cross-region replication solution based on
> AWS CloudFormation. This solution has now been deprecated in favor of
> an open source command line tool. For more information, please refer
> to the detailed instructions on
>
> GitHub:

https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-cross-region-library/blob/master/README.md

> The DynamoDB cross-region replication solution uses the Amazon
> DynamoDB Cross-Region Replication Library. This library uses DynamoDB
> Streams to keep DynamoDB tables in sync across multiple regions in
> near real time. When you write to a DynamoDB table in one region,
> those changes are automatically propagated by the Cross-Region
> Replication Library to your tables in other regions.
>
> You can leverage the Cross-Region Replication Library in your own
> applications, to build your own replication solutions with DynamoDB
> Streams. For more information, and to download the source code, go to
> the following GitHub repository:

https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-cross-region-library

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment. To prevent using any additional stuff I implemented custom replication logic.